# Why can't we use ${$#} to get the last argument passed to a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm reading Richard Blum and Christine Bresnahan's "Linux Command Line and Shell Scripting Bible."  In the section dealing with different special variables like `$#` and `$@` they point out that, although `$#` contains the index of the final parameter, it cannot be used to short-circuit to accessing the final parameter, like so: `${$#}`.  Instead, we're supposed to use `${!#}`.  Not much explanation is given for *why* this is the case, only that it's so.

That's all well and good and I will remember that should I ever go to do something like this - but is there some deeper reason buried in the mechanics of bash (or even just features that are beyond the scope of an introductory text) to explain why `${$#}` doesn't work?  I spent some time looking for an answer on the internet and couldn't uncover much.  The man page for bash touched on it, but not in a way that made any sense to me.

Comment: Because you need to do `eval echo \${$#}`, which of course is **evil** (-;!

Comment: @shellter you could; `tmpVar=$#; echo ${!tmpVar}`

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub : Good one!

Comment: Nothing ever documented parameter expansion to be recursive; if the behavior isn't documented, it doesn't exist. There's no "why" other than "that isn't a feature anyone ever built" (for bash; zsh does have something similar, but zsh and bash are mutually incompatible shells). `${!#}` is consistent with `${!varname}` to make `var=foo; echo "${!var}"` be equivalent to `echo "$foo"` (which it is).

Comment: I do not think `How ${@: -1} expand to last argument?` is not a duplicate to `Why can't we use ${$#}`. We can't use `${$#}` to get the last arguments, because variable expansions are just not recursive ad the content of `{` `}` is parsed by itself.  We can't use that, because it was never implemented. `Not much explanation is given for why this is the case, only that it's so.` While we can't explain _why_ in physics, you could think we can explain why in programming.The only answer to "why", is "because it was invented this way". The person who wrote the shell, wrote it that way, it's this way

Comment: @CharlesDuffy fair enough.  So like, if I do ${10} I'm literally grabbing the tenth parameter.  If I do a ${$#}, even if $# == 10, that's not equivalent to ${10}, then?

Comment: @KamilCuk okay, this makes sense.  So then my next question would be, if I do indeed echo ${$#} I get a random number (when I tried it, I got 5138).  Does this number have any significance at all?

Comment: Right, there's a limited number of things documented to be valid in the `...` position in `${...}`, and _other expansions aren't in that set_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why can't we use ${$#} to get the last argument passed to a shell script?

We can't use `${$#}` to get the last arguments, because variable expansions are just not recursive ad the content of `{` `}` is just parsed by shell once. We can't use that, because it was never implemented. I think there is really not much explanation here, only that it is so.

> Not much explanation is given for why this is the case, only that it's so.

While we can't explain why in physics, you could think we can explain why in programming. The only answer to "why", is "because it was invented this way". The person who wrote the (first) [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell), wrote it to work that way, it got [standardized](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) and now all the standard shells work that way.

Most probably it was written that way, because it was easy to do. I think this is the best explanation we can get.

> if I do indeed echo ${$#} I get a random number (when I tried it, I got 5138). Does this number have any significance at all?

- `echo $$` gives you PID of the current shell process.
- `echo ${$}` also gives PID of the current shell process.
- `${var#string}` removes `string` from the beginning of expansion fo `var`

  - for example `a=1234; echo ${a#12}` removes `12` from the beginning of `1234` resulting in `34`.
- The `${$#}` expands to the current pid like `$$` and then the `#` removes... "nothing" from the beginning of the variable, so it's the same as `$$`.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html the `${parameter#word}` part.

Remember to check your scripts with shellcheck https://www.shellcheck.net/ . Also check https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ .

Comment: That third/fourth bullet points I think is what I was stuck on.  Thank you so much for your detailed response here, this gave me the insight into the mechanics of parameter expansion (a new term I now know!) that I was looking for.  I'll take some time to study the link you shared.

Comment: Parameter expansion is not recursive ***in that particular way***.  There are nevertheless ways in which one parameter expansion can be recognized inside another.  As or in an array index, for example.